# Looking for best way to test when loop changes index

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, foreach, ascii

Im looking for the best practice to determine when an indexed number inside a loop changes. Take for example this foreach loop which converts the first letter of a word to the ASCII key:

```
<?php foreach($loterms as $key => $loterm) : 
$brand_id = substr($loterm->name,0,1);
$index = ord($brand_id);
endforeach; ?>
```

What I want to know is if the index changes between each run of the loop and if so run some code. For example if the ASCII key changes from 44 to 45 I want to output something different.

Comment: print `$index` on each iteration.

Comment: Sorry I might not have explained it, I want to execute some more code when the index increments by 1 or more

Comment: Store the last index in a variable and compare current index with it. If it changed, execute your code and then write the new index to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone. I ended up coding this (works like a charm):

```
<?php foreach($loterms as $key => $loterm) : 
$brand_id = substr($loterm->name,0,1);
                            if(ord($brand_id) > $index_temp):
                                echo '<li class="full-width">'.$brand_id.'</li>';
                            endif;

                            $index_temp = ord($brand_id);
endforeach; ?>
```

As @syck pointed out all I needed to do was store the index as a variable at the end of the loop then compare that variable with the new index at the start of the next loop and if it changes output my desired code.